# Create byte range index of CSV file to read from S3 row-by-row

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have large (10-100gb) CSV/Text logs files in my S3 Bucket uploaded every day, and the amazon S3 supports the RFC-7233 byte ranges header to partially read the file instead downloading the complete object.

```
var s3request = new GetObjectRequest()
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = s3Key,
                    ByteRange = new ByteRange(byteStart, byteEnd)
                };
```

Is there any way I can create an Index for each-file-each-row and store in a table to use as pagination reference? For example bytes 1 - 100 : 1st row, 101 - 200 : 2nd row and so on.

And then if I need to read first 2 rows, I can check the index to get the bytes range and then send that to `ByteRange` header

**Example CSV File**

```
Field1, Field2
a, b
c, d
e, f
g, h
i, j
k, l
x, y
```

**Example Index**

```
Row, ByteStart, ByteEnd
1, 0, 100
2, 101, 200
3, 201, 300
```

I am looking to create bytes range index in C#, before uploading the report to S3. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

My attempt to create the index

```
void Main()
{
    string path = @"Y:\temp\test-file.txt"; 
    var index = new List<RowIndex>();
    // Read file by skipping the header
    var lines = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1);
    long rowNumber = 1;
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
        // How to get the byteStart + byteEnd for this line ?

        index.Add(new RowIndex {rowNumber = rowNumber, byteStart = ? , byteEnd = ? });
        rowNumber++;
    }
    // Print the index  
}

public class RowIndex
{
    public long rowNumber {get; set;}
    public long byteStart {get;set;}
    public long byteEnd {get;set;}  
}
```

Comment: Those ranges are the locations of newlines or whatever row terminator you want. You'd have to scan the entire file once to find those locations though.

Comment: How would you be consuming the files? Would it be in your own application, or through a querying tool like Amazon Athena / Amazon EMR? Such tools can read more efficient file formats like ORC and Parquet, which are much more efficient at locating data.

Comment: The files will be read in my Web API. For example /api/reader?name=abc.csv&offset=0&limit=100

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just the new line for no, because these are csv/delimited files so "/n" means a new line start, but I would be interesting to use custom terminator as well.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Any example using parquet to read from S3? however, whatever library I use > I still need to build the index to tell the library what row(byteStart-byteEnd) I need to fetch. So, the question is still open about how to generate the bytes range for each row?

Comment: If you are just interested in reading a specific row, then your idea seems good. You would need to generate the index yourself. If you are wanting to do more complex queries on the data (eg Sum Column1 where Column2 = xxx), then I would recommend using Amazon Athena.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein How can I generate the index in c#. Any code example to read file line-by-line and get it's byteStart and byteEnd for each row? See my attempt in updated question

Comment: You would only need to store a list of Row Starts. The row obviously ends at the next `RowStart-1`. The first entry is the first row, the second entry is the second row, etc, so you do not even need a row number. Frankly, how you intend to _consume_ the index is the most important factor. Depending on how you will use it, you might not need every row — you might only need every 100 rows, or perhaps the row where a date flips over into the next day. Think backwards to come up with the best solution by thinking what you need _later_, and then making it available.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Right now, I am looking to learn how to generate the byteStart + byteEnd for each line?

Comment: Your program (similar to what you have written above) will need to use the **length of each line**, plus the newline marker, to keep a tally of the starting point for each line.